# publish dotnet core console application failed, error message 'Detected downgrade'

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to build dotnet core 2.1 console application with dotnet standard library 2.0, Use the dotnet publish command like that

```
dotnet publish -c Debug -r win10-x64
```

but it just response nuget error code NU1605
detail is

```
<<dotnet standard project name>> -> MySql.Data 8.0.17 -> SSH.NET 2016.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Dvn.png)

but when I use build(ctrl + shift + F5) in visual studio 2017/2019  is totally work.
and in the debug mode that project work fine.
So I don't know how to fix it?

Comment: Try to update assembly version

Comment: @Nehorai  Thank you for your answer.. I fix the problem but just change MySql nuget version from 8.0.17 to 6.0.X. it's so weird but work.

Comment: @Chana Great...